# How to show error message on Visualforce Page when create records based on Condition

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

**Project Requirement**:-create new record when candidate's PAN is not blacklisted, if it is blacklisted then show warning message on visualforce page and update new phone number in blacklisted candidate object.

**Pre exquisite**:- i have two object 1.Sudent_matster__c : Fields:- Name, Phone__c, PAN__c, email__c etc 2.Black_Listed_Candidate__c Fields:- Name, Phone__c, PAN__c etc

**QUESTION** When i enter blacklisted field **PAN**- FHSJF10387 then this code runs perfectly fine, but i enter another blacklisted field **PAN**- DKFIT8888S,CNYY78912Q, RYHJI997Q.etc. then code wont work. why? i think old value should be cleared from memory?

**Visual force page IMAGE** [This is visualforce page ][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLzjo.png

**VFP CODE**

```
<apex:page Controller="Class_Practice">
<apex:form id="frm" html-autocomplete="off" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;background-color:lightyellow">
   <H1 style="text-align:center;font-size:30px;">PAN DATA CHECK</H1>
   <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!newStudent.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newStudent.First_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newStudent.Last_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newStudent.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newStudent.Phone__c}"/>   
            <apex:inputField value="{!newStudent.PAN__c}"/>   
            <Apex:commandButton value="Save" Action="{!MySave}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**APEX CLASS Code**

```
public class Class_Practice
{   
public Student_Master__c newStudent {get;set;}  
Map<Id, string> IdAndBlackListPhoneMap = New Map<Id, string>();
public static list< Black_Listed_Candidate__c> blackList =[SELECT Name,PAN__c,Phone__c FROM Black_Listed_Candidate__c];

public Class_Practice()
 {
     newStudent = new Student_Master__c();
     
 }

public pageReference MySave() 
{   
    for(Black_Listed_Candidate__c bp:blacklist)
    { 
        if (bp.PAN__c==newStudent.PAN__c ) 
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'PAN is Black Listed'));
            bp.Phone__c = newStudent.Phone__c;
            IdAndBlackListPhoneMap.put(bp.Id, bp.Phone__c);
            Update blacklist;
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            insert newStudent;
            PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + newStudent.Id);
            pg.setRedirect(true);
            return pg;
            }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**THANK YOU**